# Dynamically created elements are hiding Bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, safari, z-index, popover

This is a pretty straight forward problem. It only occurs in Safari. I have a popover on an element. This is all well and good so far. I have an interactive element that dynamically adds a div to the DOM. Once this element is added, any popover that occurs in the same position is behind the dynamically added element (vision is obscured).

**EDIT: Just to be clear the dynamic element is an iframe. I attempted adding a static iframe to the page and the problem still occurs in Safari. Is there some sort of crazy auto iframe styling that happens in Safari?**

**EDIT2: Maybe code examples will help show that I have tried z-index**

css for dynamic element

```
.active_tv_screen{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border-radius:5px;
    z-index:3 !important;
}
```

custom styling for popover to try and force it in front of dynamic element

```
.popover {
    z-index: 1001 !important;
    position:absolute;
    max-height:500px !important;
}
```

Reminder: this problem is Safari speicific

Comment: have you tried to use z-index attribute?

Comment: yes I have tried using the z-index to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fix - add ?wmode=opaque to the end of the embed url (the src attribute) and it will be fixed. The problem is the new flash player.

Source: https://maxmorgandesign.com/fix_youtube_iframe_overlay_and_z_index_issues/

Answer (score 0):

set the 'z-index' of the element you want to remain visible higher than the 'z-index' of the other elements. don't forget you'll need to specify a position: absolute | relative | etc...